# How to call WM_SETREDRAW?

Tags: c, winapi

When I send `WM_SETREDRAW` to disable redraw for a window, how do I "restore" the previous state when I'm done?

What's the proper way to send this message?

Comment: see the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). call SendMessage once with FALSE to turn off redraw, call it again with TRUE to turn on redraw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous answer is outdated. It is now possible to check the redraw state *for controls that call `DefWindowProc`*. (Note that this may *not* include your common controls of interest.)

[From MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-setredraw):

> **Windows 10 and later; Windows Server 2016 and later.** The system sets a property named `SysSetRedraw` on a window whose window procedure passes `WM_SETREDRAW` messages to `DefWindowProc`. You can use the `GetProp` function to get the property value when it's available. `GetProp` returns a non-zero value when redraw is disabled. `GetProp` will return zero when redraw is enabled, or when the window property doesn't exist.

Comment: Unfortunately, the SysSetRedraw property does not seem very useful as any window which actually handles WM_SETREDRAW in a meaningful way will not let it pass to DefWIndowProc, and this seems to include the Win32 common controls (or the combobox at least). At least from my own testing, if I didn't make a mistake.

Comment: @LeoDavidson: Unfortunately yeah, that's why I put the parentheses there. It's still nice though for having a standard property to save & restore the information to.

Answer (score 3):

You can't *restore the previous state*, as there is no way to access the current state. There is no `WM_GETREDRAW`. Once you are done you send `WM_SETREDRAW` again with `TRUE` as an argument this time, and if anyone else had set redraw to `FALSE` on an outer scope then well.. that's bad for them..

Comment: "too bad for them"... more like, too bad for me... :\

Comment: @Mehrdad: If you are in control of the window class, you can handle `WM_SETREDRAW` yourself and count the calls...

Comment: Yeah, or even if I'm not, I can still replace the window procedure... I was wondering if there's a 'correct' way to do this though, but I guess not.  (I guess now it's not surprising why people call `LockWindowUpdate` instead, even though they're not supposed to.)

Comment: Surely you know how many times you call `WM_SETREDRAW` on your own window? Doing this on someone elses window is just asking for trouble if they're not expecting it.

Comment: @Deanna Depends on your definition of *"me"*. I turn off redraw, then some code library i depend on may, or may not, also turn off (and then on) redraw. So i may, or may not, come back from a function call with redraw on. Yes it's *"me"* as in i'm the one who wrote the application - but now the one who wrote all the code.

Comment: @ianboyd: but in that case, it is still not "you" that is doing it,  the library is assuming it as the right to do as it wishes to someone else's window. Ideally,  it should ask the owner or similar.

Comment: @Deanna Well i'm passing it the Window. Today's example is a spell-checker library. You pass it a handle to a Windows `RichEdit` control. While formatting of the text is being updated (i.e. adding red squiggles under misspelled words), the spellchecker *might* disable re-draw. At the same time, my code that (eventually) calls the SpellChecker might have had a higher-level layer disable re-draws.